# Cannot open PDF using xcode for my iphone app

Tags: swift, swift5, xcode11, pdfkit, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

I have an iPhone app and I implemented a `UIDocumentPickerViewController`. Once the user chooses a `PDF` I receive the `URL` of the PDF.

I'm trying to get the Data for that PDF so I could send it to my server, but I get the following response:

```swift
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=257 "The file “aaa.pdf” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/9C57E7F1-0997-4F57-A3EF-A7EFC3EF6158/File Provider Storage/aaa.pdf, NSUnderlyingError=0x282b43600 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"}}
```

This is how I try to convert it to Data:

```swift
        var documentData = Data()
        do {
            documentData.append(try Data(contentsOf: documentURL))
        } catch {
            throw Error.Creation
        }
```

I've read somewhere that sandboxed apps cannot read files, but when I'm looking into the target capabilities, I don't even see the Sandbox capability.

Any ideas why that happens?
Thanks

Comment: Please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/59573299/6920041

Comment: Where does the user choose the PDF file from? Where are these PDF files located?

Comment: @EarlGrey it's located in "On My iPhone" and I pick it with the UIDocumentPickerViewController

Comment: @matt Read it just now.. Apparently i used .open and not .import. That did the trick. If you want to write that answer i'll be happy to accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the issue was I was using ".open" when creating the document picker instead of ".import". That did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Updated to Swift 5 - Xcode 12:

In order to have read permission to the file you imported, add `asCopy: true` to the document picker:

```
let doc = UIDocumentPickerViewController(forOpeningContentTypes: types, asCopy: true)
```